# Cast to custom type fails

Tags: c#, linq, casting

I'm maintaining a program created by someone else (argh).  When populating a custom class from a LINQ query, the following statement produces an error that `Specified cast is not valid`.
But is does not do it for all records in the ContactPersons view, only for some - even though the records looks the same to me.

How can I determine why the cast is failing?

```
var smDataContext = new SurveyManagerDataClassesDataContext(dbConnectionString);

ContactPerson contactPerson =
    (from contactPersons in smDataContext.ContactPersons
     where (contactPersons.ContactPersonID.Trim().ToUpper()
            == this.ContactPersonID.Trim().ToUpper())
     select contactPersons)
    .FirstOrDefault<ContactPerson>();
```

The class looks like this:

```
public partial class ContactPerson
{
    private string _ContactPersonID;
    private string _Surname;
    private string _FirstName;
    private string _EMail;
    private string _CompanyID;
    private System.Nullable<bool> _IsDefaultForAdhocSurvey;
    private System.Nullable<bool> _IsDefaultForClosingOfTasksSurvey;
    private System.Nullable<bool> _IsDefaultForScheduledProjectSurvey;
    private System.Nullable<bool> _IsDefaultForScheduledContractSurvey;

    public ContactPerson()
    {
    }
    ...
```

Sample data:
This data copied and pasted from the view that reads data directly from multiple tables:

```
ContactPersonID Surname FirstName   EMail               CompanyID   IsDefaultForAdhocSurvey IsDefaultForClosingOfTasksSurvey    IsDefaultForScheduledProjectSurvey  IsDefaultForScheduledContractSurvey
Patrick Grey    Grey    Patrick     patrick@grey.co.za  2410955     0   0   1   0
Patrick Black   Black   Patrick     patrick@black.co.za 2410955     0   0   1   0
```

Doing this does not work though:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ContactPersonsView]
AS
SELECT
    'Patrick Grey' as ContactPersonID,
    'Grey' as Surname,
    'Patrick' As FirstName,
    'patrick@grey.co.za' AS Email,
    '1234' as CompanyID,
    0 as IsDefaultForAdhocSurvey,
    0 as IsDefaultForClosingOfTasksSurvey,
    1 as IsDefaultForScheduledProjectSurvey,
    0 as IsDefaultForScheduledContractSurvey
```

Comment: What's the type of `smDataContext.ContactPersons`?

Comment: What is the type of `smDataContext.ContactPersons`?

Comment: Also post the original error message. I'm pretty sure, it won't be `The custom cast is invalid`

Comment: This usually happens when some property on the c# Object does not macth the type of the column. Can you show the table structure??...

Comment: So there is no cast operator implemented on the ContactPerson class? If there is not, the properties would have to match exactly, like @LucaPerotti said.

Comment: Your questions are appreciated.  Original post amended with answers.

Comment: I agree with @Soppus but there is no cast on the class, and the data is not complex - Some strings, some booleans.  My create view statement above shows that the data is in the correct format.  There must be something else I guess.  Will keep on searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all your comments.  I should have converted my boolean values to bits.

Thus, if I change my view from:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ContactPersonsView]
AS

    SELECT 'Patrick Grey' as ContactPersonID, 'Grey' as Surname, 'Patrick' As FirstName, 'patrick@grey.co.za' AS Email, '1234' as CompanyID,
    0 as IsDefaultForAdhocSurvey, 0 as IsDefaultForClosingOfTasksSurvey, 1 as IsDefaultForScheduledProjectSurvey, 0 as IsDefaultForScheduledContractSurvey
```

to this:

```
SELECT 'Patrick Grey' as ContactPersonID, 'Grey' as Surname, 'Patrick' As FirstName, 'patrick@grey.co.za' AS Email, '1234' as CompanyID,
CONVERT(bit, 0) as IsDefaultForAdhocSurvey, CONVERT(bit, 0) as IsDefaultForClosingOfTasksSurvey, CONVERT(bit, 1) as IsDefaultForScheduledProjectSurvey, CONVERT(bit, 0) as IsDefaultForScheduledContractSurvey
```

then it works.